# Best way to handle a local SQL server communication with a cloud SQL server? (.NET Web App)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I have a .NET web-app (4.5) the app is a cloud app in the sense that it is hosted remotely and has its own local SQL data source.

The web app needs to talk to client SQL servers (in this case lets say my local SQL database).  At the core the web app will request data from the remote SQL source and save it to the local SQL source, or the other way around the web-app may notify the remote SQL source that it needs to update a particular record, etc.

What would be the best way to do this?

I was looking at just doing a windows service on the client SQL server, and the web app makes calls to the client SQL box web service telling it what it needs to update or send over?

I started looking into WCF would this be a good application of WCF?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider implementing an OData service as a [WCF Data Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) hosted in IIS that exposes data queried from SQL Server.

The following MSDN article provides an overview of a SQL Server OData implementation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192995.aspx

The following CodePlex link seems to provide good and relevant information pertaining to your scenario:
http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/101644

Regards,

Comment: Thanks after doing some more research it seems like OData as WCF Data Service is the way to go.

On the server side of it, some of the operations are quite large, for example the initial fill from the Odata source may have thousands of records, should i just bake it into the web-app, or should i create a separate service or console application to pull\push data to the local SQL?

Comment: I am not sure entirely sure I understand your question ...  If you are wondering about the overall WCF Data Service architecture, then the following MSDN article should help [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336022.aspx].  If on the other hand you are wondering about caching large data sets, then the following MSDN blog should help [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/11/17/using-asp-net-output-caching-with-wcf-data-services.aspx].  In either case, both articles are worth reviewing. Good Luck.